# Get catalina.base environment variable value from context.xml

Tags: tomcat, environment-variables

Is it possible to access an environment variable from the context.xml file in Tomcat?
I have tried `${catalina.home}/mypath`
But that is not working

Is there a way to get the docBase from context.xml?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which Tomcat version, but the following holds for Tomcat 8

${catalina.base} can be accessed from context.xml - this will give you the value of CATALINA_BASE, which defaults to CATALINA_HOME unless otherwise specified.

Additionally, system properties can be accessed from context.xml - so if you have a -Dtest.property=something on your command-line (in CATALINA_OPTS etc), you can access this from context.xml via ${test.property}.